# Where to download ASP .NET 1.1.4322 x64?

Tags: 64-bit, .net-framework

Please can you tell me where I can download the x64 version of ASP .NET 1.1.4322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a 32bit version of the ASP .NET 1.1 was produced.

64bit was introduced with ASP .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can google search for

> ASP .NET 1.1.4322

or you can click [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26).

Comment: Thanks, but that is the 32 bit version. I haven't been able to find an X64 version. From https://support.microsoft.com/am-et/help/894435/how-to-switch-between-the-32-bit-versions-of-asp-net-1-1-and-the-64-bi it looks like 1.1 only came in a 32 bit version, 64 bit was introduced from version .NET 2.0

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm sorry I wasn't paying attention. Regarding the versions that does seem plausible. 
Reading up on this lends strength to the thought. (same page)
[Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/894435/how-to-switch-between-the-32-bit-versions-of-asp-net-1-1-and-the-64-bi)

Answer (score 0):

Download .net 1.1. from here :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26